# Composite pattern, why is it bad if "children" know about "parent"?

Tags: php, composition

code samples: https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/composite/php I made something similar, except that "`OnTheBookShelf`" knows about $books (`SeveralBooks`). My "boss" say its bad that they know about each other. But why?

Allright, I edit it:

```
abstract class OnTheBookShelf {
    public $shelf; /////////////////////////////////////////////////
    abstract function getBookInfo($previousBook);
    abstract function getBookCount();
    abstract function setBookCount($new_count);
    abstract function addBook($oneBook);
    abstract function removeBook($oneBook);
}

class OneBook extends OnTheBookShelf {
    private $title;
    private $author;
    function __construct($title, $author) {
      $this->title = $title;
      $this->author = $author;
    }
    function getBookInfo($bookToGet) {
      if (1 == $bookToGet) {
        return $this->title." by ".$this->author;
      } else {
        return FALSE;
      }
    }
    function getBookCount() {
      return 1;
    }
    function setBookCount($newCount) {
      return FALSE;
    }
    function addBook($oneBook) {
      return FALSE;
    }
    function removeBook($oneBook) {
      return FALSE;
    }
}

class SeveralBooks extends OnTheBookShelf {
    private $oneBooks = array();
    private $bookCount;
    public function __construct() {
      $this->setBookCount(0);
    }
    public function getBookCount() {
      return $this->bookCount;
    }
    public function setBookCount($newCount) {
      $this->bookCount = $newCount;
    }
    public function getBookInfo($bookToGet) {   
      if ($bookToGet <= $this->bookCount) {
        return $this->oneBooks[$bookToGet]->getBookInfo(1);
      } else {
        return FALSE;
      }
    }
    public function addBook($oneBook) {
      $oneBook->shelf = $this; //////////////////////////////////////////////////
      $this->setBookCount($this->getBookCount() + 1);
      $this->oneBooks[$this->getBookCount()] = $oneBook;
      return $this->getBookCount();
    }
    public function removeBook($oneBook) {
      $counter = 0;
      while (++$counter <= $this->getBookCount()) {
        if ($oneBook->getBookInfo(1) == 
          $this->oneBooks[$counter]->getBookInfo(1)) {
          for ($x = $counter; $x < $this->getBookCount(); $x++) {
            $this->oneBooks[$x] = $this->oneBooks[$x + 1];
          }
          $this->setBookCount($this->getBookCount() - 1);
        }
      }
      return $this->getBookCount();
    }
}
```

I added a bunch of //////////////// to the problematic lines. And here they say that book has reference to shelf.

Comment: Please show some concrete example. In a composite pattern, there isn't usually any "parent/child" relationship; that's something that relates to class inheritance. Does `Book extend Bookshelf` in your case *and* `Bookshelf` is composed of `Books`, or what...?

Answer (score 1):

They should know about their interfaces, so that they can be changed.

Let's say you have classes:

```
Bookshelf
  private books: Book[]

Book
  public title: String
```

You would then access `books[i].title` and display title of the a book.

Now imagine that the programmer in charge of `Book` decides that the title merrits its own class, so we have:

```
Book
  public title: Title

Title
  private t: String
  public toString()
```

Now the programmer who was coding `Bookshelf` is required to change their code.

On the other hand if we would have:

```
Book
  private title: String
  public getTitleString()
```

Then we could change the implementation of the `Book` class, and all we would have to do is to write the `getTitleString()` function that would return a string representation of a title, and everything would continue to work without any additional changes to `Bookshelf`.

Answer (score 1):

> My "boss" say its bad that they know about each other. But why?

The problem is circular reference between `Shelf` and `Book` that is not so trivial and requires special care to work with.

For example, if you simply write `$oneBook->shelf = $this;` inside `addBook` method, then what happens if consumer calls this method for one book on two different shelves?

```
$book = new Book;
$shelf1 = new Shelf;
$shelf2 = new Shelf;

$shelf1->addBook($book);
$shelf2->addBook($book);
```

`Book` will be added to both shelves, but it will hold reference only to the last shelf, which leads to inconsistency and potential run-time bugs.

Of cause, circular reference can be done right, but it requires special attention and adds complexity to code.